# Term for buzzing or hissing sound often created by vibration

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, vocabulary, terminology, technical

Specifically, I am referring to the hissing, buzzing, S-like, or fuzzy sound that is created when electronic speakers play sounds or music near their volume or frequency limits.

I recall having learned a term for this at some point in the recent past, but cannot remember it despite significant time spent searching online.  If I recall correctly, this is a sound produced within the speaker, not just sound caused by the speaker vibrating adjacent objects.

Comment: If you're still looking for a more detailed answer, you could cross-post at the Audio-Video Production Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sibilance* is a word for that type of sound. It tends to be caused by [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) of frequencies that are above the range of human hearing.

Comment: That was the work I was looking for.  Thank you.  I've now been able to do some more detailed reading on how to avoid this in speaker configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for "[white noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise)"?

Comment: What I was thinking of wasn't really noise distributed across the full spectrum like white noise.  It's generally concentrated more around a small frequency range.  Thanks for pointing me to that article, it was a good read.

Answer (score 0):

An [webervst.com spterm.html](http://www.webervst.com/spterm.html) webpage defines numerous terms for speaker-related distortions, including *Boomy, Breakup, Buzz, Rattle, Cone Cry, Ghost Notes, Edge Yowl, Crunch, Damping, Diffused, Fizz, Flabbing, Farting Out, Harsh, Honking, Muddy, Peaky, Presence Notch, Voice Coil Rub*. The web page attributes buzz and rattle to speaker damage, caused for example by exceeding a speaker's power limits.

Some of the distortions above are due to *breakup*, that is, to a speaker vibrating in sections rather than as a smooth single surface.  The web page notes that "comb filtering and other anomalies" occur due to breakup.  Breakup is a natural consequence of driving a physical device faster (*ie* at a higher frequency) than it can move as a whole.

Comment: Thank you.  That was an interesting page to read.  Based on those definitions, it looks like breakup or harsh are probably most closely related to what I am trying to describe.  Neither is exactly the word I was looking for, but at least I can now refer to the phenomenon in a way that people familiar with speakers will understand.